# Saving or printing screen screenshot explanation

Tags: android, printing

How to save screenshot of the application screen or search for a wifi printer and print the application screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the screen shot:

```
View view=mTextView.getRootView(); /*mTextView is a textview on my screen. Instead you can take any of your views(imageview, textview or even button)*/
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp=view.getDrawingCache();
```

Now, you save bitmap to a file to save it.

EDIT:
I wonder if you are not asking about programmatic way? If you are looking for manual way, Raj's answer may help you.

Comment: Excuse the ignorance, if I want to put the User save a screenshot of a button.
Just create the button and put this code that you gave me in the event of the button?

Answer (score 0):

Following steps will help for saving screen shot.

1. Run App in the emulator device.
2. open device option in the eclipse and select corresponding device which your are running the app.
3. select corresponding package of your app in the device.
4. click on screen capture button to take screen shot.
5. click on the save button to save the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

For Screenshot use following code,

```
myView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap myScreenshot = myView.getDrawingCache();
```

Now you can save this image on SD card with File API or if you want to send it to WiFi Printer then you need to do Connection with WiFi Printer and then send Bitmap Image to Printer for printing.