# How to take printout of my layout using wifi printer?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-wifi, android-print-framework

I am developing Restaurant application. After the order completion, i need to  display bill (items price and total amount) in `AlertView`.

Is it possible to take print out of that `AlertView` in wifi printer? How to make it?

Comment: Check out this question :- http://stackoverflow.com/q/9326148/1384010

May be it helps you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to print a layout create a bitmap from the layout and send a intent to the printer app as in the following code

```
    yourRootLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    yourRootLayout.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    yourRootLayout.buildDrawingCache();

    Bitmap dummyImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(yourRootLayout
            .getDrawingCache());
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    dummyImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    byte[] photoArray = out.toByteArray();
    yourRootLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    try {

        File file = new File(getFilePath());//path to sdcard
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        FileOutputStream outPut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        outPut.write(photoArray);
        outPut.flush();
        outPut.close();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivity(intent);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error generating file", e);
    }
```

now this will pop a a list of apps you will have to select the printers app that allows printing via wifi

Comment: what is mWebView here?